# Starting GVim at size and position it was last closed

Tags: vim, windows-xp

Is there a way that GVim could be set up in Windows XP, so that when it starts it has exactly the same size and position as the instance that was last closed?

It is annoying when you're working with a documentation file in the browser in the background, a command prompt window (constantly open) and a Vim instance that keeps jumping all over the place upon starting/closing. Naturally, it always starts over the paragraph you're currently reading :)

Comment: You can set up gVim to start with exactly the same size and position every time, supposing the size and position you want is "maximized". If that is acceptable, put `au GUIEnter * simalt ~x` in your `.vimrc`. Yes, I know this is a lot like Henry Ford's "any color you want as long as it's black". So I am not offering this as an answer.

Comment: Another possibility is to install Cygwin/X and gVim with X support. I say "possibility" because I have not tried it. gVim with X support ought to honor the `-geometry` option, though, letting you start it with arbitrary geometry. I do have experience using Cygwin/X and various X applications other than gVim, and there is no problem setting window geometry in general, so I have no reason to believe it won't work.

Comment: Related: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Maximize_or_set_initial_window_size

Comment: @sehe - Yeah, I got that part. I think I even got it to remember the old settings from the previous instance. But how to set the initial position of a new instance? Any ideas ... ?

Comment: @ldigas: i found this [page](http://www.pcmech.com/article/how-to-saving-window-position-xp-dual-monitor/) - dunno if it contains any good info (looks crappy to me, but I thought I'd mention it anyway). The most conclusive thing that seems to pop up is: you can do this with paid software in windows... (sic)

Comment: @sehe - Ultramon? Yeah, I used to actually use that thing for a while (had it on a work laptop left by a coleague). // Well, anyways, I'll keep looking. If I find something practical I'll post it here.